# How to confine the negative scope?

Tags: negation

> She is not beautiful.

There are two explanations:

1. It is a negative sentence. She/ ***is not*** / beautiful.
   "not" is an adverb which modifies "is";
2. It is an affirmative sentence. She/ is /***not beautiful***.

   "not" is an adverb which modifies "beautiful";

I want to know more about the negative scope in the sentence and how to judge its negative sentence.

Comment: Well this stack is to help people trying to learn English, but you have to stop being lazy. Please see this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmative_and_negative) on negation and affirmative sentences, and trust me, it is very detailed. I am sure you will get your answer if you read the article. Next thing is, She/is/not beautiful is still negative.

Comment: Which one do you think is correct? (And I ask all the responders this.) X said, "Z isn't very smart." Then Y said... a) "She is not beautiful, too." or b) "She is not beautiful, either."

Answer (score 1):

If I had to ask someone about her, I would ask "How is she?" I would not ask "How is she not?" A cursory answer to my query "How is she?" would be "not beautiful". Hence, I consider 'not' to be an attribute of 'beautiful' and not 'is'.

Your second interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is an exercise of [bikeshedding](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bikeshedding), but I can't help myself playing logic riddles.

Both your sentences are grammatically correct. In fact, both are written the same:

> 1. She **is not** beautiful
> 2. She is **not beautiful**

Furthermore, both sentences have the same meaning. The only potential difference that I can imagine is in the intonation by a conscious speaker.

**What is the cause of this ambiguity?** It is the result of the unusual properties of the adverb "not":

- the adverb "not" precedes the adjective it modifies (**not + adjective**)
- the adverb "not" follows the auxiliary verb it modifies (**auxiliary verb + not**)

**Is it possible to generate this kind of ambiguity using a full verb?** This kind of ambiguity is not possible because only an auxiliary verb can be modified directly by the adverb "not". If we try to do the same trick with a full lexical verb, we end up with:

> 1. She **does not look** beautiful
> 2. She looks **not beautiful**

And it is clear what word is modified by the adverb "not".

**Is it possible to generate this kind of ambiguity using other adverbs?** Yes, it is:

> 1. My dreams **become always** true
> 2. My dreams become **always true**

:)

Answer (score 0):

Your first interpretation is correct.

> She is not [beautiful]

And affirmative sentence with (more or less!) the same meaning would be

> She is ugly.

In some cases, you can change the meaning of a sentence by applying not differently:

> I try not to be late.

I am actually doing my best to make sure I am not late.

> I do not try to be late.

I am not trying anything. If I am late or not, it is not because I tried for it.